# How to access object created in class constructor

Tags: c++, qt

My GUI class in constructor is creating new object of my database class. It looks like that:

```
GUI::GUI(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    Baza *plik = new Baza();
    connect(ui.insertBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &GUI::run);
}
```

I've managed to get user input from QDialog:

```
void GUI::run() {
    DialogInput dialog;
    dialog.exec();
    site_text = dialog.getSite();
}
```

How should I pass `site_text` to function in `Baza` class? I need to use that object (plik) created in GUI constructor but I can't access it from `GUI::run()` function.

Comment: Don't declare it in your constructor, declare it in your class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `plik` to the declaration of `GUI`:

```
class GUI : public QWidget {
    // ...
    Baza* plik;
};
```

then in the constructor

```
GUI::GUI(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    plik = new Baza();
    connect(ui.insertBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &GUI::run);
}
```

As your code stands, `plik` is leaked as soon as GUI constructor completes.

Clean up `plik` in the destructor:

```
GUI::~GUI()
{
    // ...
    delete plik;
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::unique_ptr` to store `plik` in `GUI` so you don't need to remember to destruct it. Or, if `plik` benefits from deriving from `QObject` (e.g. for signals and slots), you can parent it to the `GUI` and Qt will handle the destruction. In both cases, this advice assumes `plik` has the same lifetime as `GUI`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a pointer inside the constructor the scope of the object is till the end of the constructor.

You need to create a global private variable to GUI class for that variable to be accessed by all the method in the same class. `Baza * pLink;`

When you create a pointer in the constructor, do not forget to delete the same pointer in the Destruction.

```
class GUI : public QWidget{
   //...
   GUI();
   ~GUI();
private:
   Baza * pLink;
}

GUI::GUI(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    pLink = new Baza();
    connect(ui.insertBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &GUI::run);
}

GUI::~GUI()
{
    delete pLink;
}

void GUI::run() {
    DialogInput dialog;
    dialog.exec();
    site_text = dialog.getSite();
    /* use the pointer to call the method to pass site_text */
    pLink->SomeMethod(site_text);
}
```

Naming convention would play a big role when you are declaring local variables for the function and the global variables for the class.
So use `pLink` or consider using `m_pLink` where `m_` would be added to all the global variable and `p` for pointer type.

Comment: "or consider using m_pLink where m_ would be added to all the global variable" prefixing "m_" to global variables would be slightly unorthodox, you probably meant member variables.